# Getting out of a while loop earlier with cout using c++

Tags: c++

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string sentence = "some random sentence";
    int i = 0; //runs through the bigger string
    int j = 0; //runs through the smaller string
    int k = 0; //variable to mark the position where the string starts being equal in order to delete it using substring
    string remove = "random";
    int a = sentence.size();
    int b = remove.size();
    while (i < a)
    {
        if (sentence[i] == remove[j])
        {
            if (b == j - 1)
            {
                cout << sentence.substr(0, k) << sentence.substr(i, (a - 1));
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                i++;
                j++;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            i++;
            j = 0;
            k++;

        }

    }
        return 1;
}
```

I want to remove the word random from the bigger string and print it out but when I run the code, it does not return anything. What's missing?
I already tried putting a break right below de "cout", but it does not work.

Thank you :)

Comment: you cannot access a word using sentence[i], that will only give a single character at the ith location

Comment: sentence[i] compares character by character and I save the initial position where things are equal and the last position where the word finishes. With that I write a substring until the first letter of that word and another substring starting at the end of the last letter of that word.

Answer (score 0):

As *b == 6*, *j* would have to be 7 in order for *b == j-1* to become true. But *remove[6]* is the terminating \0 of the *random* string, so *j* can never grow beyond 6.

Comment: Thanks, I see it now. (( b - 1) == j) instead of (b == j - 1)
there's some other issues with this code but now at least it returns something. Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code I edited

```
if (b-1 == j)
{
    cout << sentence.substr(0, k) << sentence.substr(i+2, (a - 1));
    break;
}
```

This is assuming, you have spaces between the words.

Comment: I just figured it out. Thank you for the reply and help :)